# How is soft selection in 3D DCC such as maya implemented?

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender, maya

In DCC, we can soft select things with proper falloff in volume/viewport. I think I can do the soft selection with viewport falloff. But how is volume falloff implemented especially with lasso/poly selection mode?

In lasso/poly selection mode, the 2D selection area in viewport is irregular polygon. Then selected objects will also in an irregular 3D space. How to do volume falloff based on this irregular 3D space to achieve soft selection?

Comment: This is a programming forum, not a 3d forum. You're going to get next to little answers here.

Comment: possibly using shaders and ray picking ... but only the devs of SW in question would know for sure ...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this can only be answered by the developers. But a quite easy method would be to use a kdtree and for every selected point simply add a falloff value to every point in the required distance.